# Array from pregmatch_all to csv

Tags: php, arrays, regex, csv, preg-match-all

I need to write all the matches(except the ones that have "DESCATALOGADO" in the end of the match) from the pregmatch_all of a string into a CSV.

```
$pdfText= nl2br($text);

$patternECO = '/^(ECO(?!GEST|DE)(?!GEST|DE)[-\/\w]+(?: [UPMNB]{1,3}(?= ))*) ([^\r\n]+\S)/m' ;
preg_match_all($patternECO, $text, $matches);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    fputcsv($fp, $match);
}

fclose($fp);
```

For example i get from pregmatch_all

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => ECO-698 Acondicionador Frio-Calor 
        [1] => ECO-CHI-522 Chimenea eléctrica con patas 
        [2] => ECO-CHI-530 Calefactor purificador 
        [3] => ECO-3005 Halógeno Oscilante 400-800-1200 Watts DESCATALOGADO
```

i want a csv like so

```
ECO-698;Acondicionador Frio-Calor;
ECO-CHI-522;Chimenea eléctrica con patas;
ECO-CHI-530;Calefactor purificador;
```

Comment: Share your source text, please

Comment: here https://regex101.com/r/wbuCAE/6

Comment: At this section of your pattern, [UPMNB]{1,3} You are saying that these characters can be followed by a space. So how do you except, Acondicionador Frio-Calor be one part of your result?! It starts with A. look at this: https://regex101.com/r/wmUKhp/1

Comment: [UPMNB]{1,3} is when you see somethng like ECO-762 N ECO-8200-2 B, the regex match everything i want but i dont know how to order the matches to make the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` option so that you'll get all the capture groups from each match together in the same row of results.

Then in your loop, remove element `0` from the row, because that's the entire match, but you only want to write the capture groups to the file.

```
$patternECO = '/^(ECO(?!GEST|DE)(?!GEST|DE)[-\/\w]+(?: [UPMNB]{1,3}(?= ))*) ([^\r\n]+\S)/m' ;
preg_match_all($patternECO, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    array_shift($match);
    fputcsv($fp, $match);
}

fclose($fp);
```